# Getting TypeError: e is undefined with js addon datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I've been trying to add datetimepicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) functionality to my form, but first, I created simple html file to test that library. It is not working. Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Test Environment</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form>
    <input id="appointment-form" name="app" value="">
</form>
</div>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#appointment-form').datetimepicker();
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

And I get

```
 TypeError: e is undefined

...eturn t?u.length:u?nt.error(e):L(e,a).slice(0)}function at(e,t,r){var i=t.dir,s=...

jquery....min.js (line 2)
```

All libraries loaded in correct order, do not know what else to do

**UPDATE:**
Added link to the datetimepicker library

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add a link to the plug-in you're using? `datetimepicker` is a generic tag that doesn't provide that info. It'd also be cool if you didn't strip file and line information, though I guess the error happens inside jQuery itself.

Comment: Alvaro, thanks for reply, updated question with mote details

Comment: Weird but your code works for me as is (using [current version](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js))...

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded again that library and it worked ) 
Thanks to Alvaro, this silly question can be closed.